# materialize css hover effect not working properly

Tags: materialize

Trying to add hover effect for the div contain the img with the class: `materialboxed`

unfortunately, it is not working together.
Any ideas?
<    https://codepen.io/taldevlop/pen/WNvGWqQ?

```
    <div class="masonry tiles">
                 <div class="col s4 tile gallery item">
         <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/216995/1.jpg" alt="" class="materialboxed responsive-img">
                         <div class="details">
                             <span class="title">Title</span>
                             <span class="description">Description</span>
                         </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
```

Comment: Hey. Could you show an example of what you're trying to achieve? Or describe it more clearly?

Comment: Hi! sorry for the poor explantation. 
I am trying to have the hover effect (you can see the tiles div) on top of the materialboxed. But it looks like they not really compatble togther. the materialboxed is not working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, several things wrong here:

1) You haven't included jQuery, but you're trying to initialise materialbox with jQuery. So either include jQuery in your project/pen, or use the vanilla JS initialisation as per the [documentation](https://materializecss.com/media.html).

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.materialboxed');
    var instances = M.Materialbox.init(elems);
  });

  // Or with jQuery

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.materialboxed').materialbox();
  });
```

Here is a codepen using jQuery and fixed up a little.

https://codepen.io/doughballs/pen/zYGowBp

2) If you look at your code, you've got a random image right at the bottom before your scripts:

```
<div class="masonry tiles">
                     <div class="col s4 tile gallery item">
             <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/216995/1.jpg" alt="" class="materialboxed responsive-img">
                             <div class="details">
                                 <span class="title">Title</span>
                                 <span class="description">Description</span>
                             </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
<!-- What is this image? -->
<img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/216995/1.jpg" alt="" class="materialboxed responsive-img">
```

3) I took off .responsive-img and instead set .materialboxed to be width: 100%

```
.materialboxed {
  width:100%;
}
```

I'm not really sure what you're trying to achieve. Hope this helps in some way.

Comment: So I think the problem starts when there are multiple images in the tiles div, it looks like the images just overlapping each other. 
Any idea?

Comment: it was the  opacity: 0.99; on the .tiles .tile .
Thanks !!